# How to generate arguments of a function

Tags: r

I have a matrix`p`, each column is an argument of function `expand.grid`, how do I have something like `expand.grid(p[,1],p[,2],...)`?

Answer (score 1):

We may convert the `matrix` to a `list` of vectors and apply `expand.grid`

```
expand.grid(asplit(p, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
expand.grid(data.frame(p))
```